# Where is the generic.xaml file located?

Tags: xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk, generic.xaml

If you want to use the default styles, colors, etc..., you need to bring them from the **generic.xaml** file that comes with **WindowsAppSDK** NuGet packages.

Hence the question, where is located the **generic.xaml** file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Option 1 (open-source): WinUI 3 on GitHub

The WinUI 3 source code is available on GitHub:

- [WinUI 3 v1.5 `generic.xaml`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/winui3/release/1.5-stable/dxaml/xcp/dxaml/themes/generic.xaml)
- [Uncompiled styles & templates for WinUI 3 v1.5](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/winui3/release/1.5-stable/controls/dev/CommonStyles)

The [WinUI 3 Gallery](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9p3jfpwwdzrc?launch=true&mode=full&hl=en-us&gl=us&ocid=bingwebsearch) app even includes handy links to these styles:

[image: The Source button on the Button page with an option labeled 'Control source code']

### Option 2 (local): look in the NuGet package

You can find the default **generic.xaml** inside each **WindowsAppSDK** NuGet package folder.

```
%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk
```

For example, in the case of **WindowsAppSDK v1.2.230118.102**, you can find 3 **generic.xaml** files.

First, let's locate the folder for the **WindowsAppSDK v1.2.230118.102** NuGet package.

```
%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.2.230118.102
```

or

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.2.230118.102
```

**Note**: Replace **USERNAME** with your user name.

Now, inside this folder you'll find 3 **generic.xaml** files.

- \lib\net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0\Microsoft.WinUI\Themes\generic.xaml
- \lib\net6.0-windows10.0.18362.0\Microsoft.WinUI\Themes\generic.xaml
- \lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.UI\Themes\generic.xaml

AFAIK, these **generic.xaml** files are identical as long as they belong the same **WindowsAppSDK** version. But keep in mind that **generic.xaml** might be different between **WindowsAppSDK** versions.

### Further resources

Additional sources thanks to @YangXiaoPo-MSFT and @mm8:

- microsoft-xaml-ui [build project](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/871c27e3681787d007c1d51c64ba4873e35e75c6/build/NuSpecs/MUXControlsFrameworkPackage.nuspec#L31) shows the path.
- [XAML theme resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources)

More source code:

- [Older WinUI 3 v1.4 `generic.xaml`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/winui3/release/1.4-stable/dxaml/xcp/dxaml/themes/generic.xaml)
- [Older uncompiled styles & templates for WinUI 3 v1.4](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/winui3/release/1.5-stable/controls/dev/CommonStyles)
- [Uncompiled styles and templates for WinUI 2](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/winui2/main/dev)

---

Updates:

- March 2024: added WinUI 3 source links
- Feb 2023: added WinUI 2 source links

Comment: microsoft-ui-xaml [build project](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/871c27e3681787d007c1d51c64ba4873e35e75c6/build/NuSpecs/MUXControlsFrameworkPackage.nuspec#L31) shows the output. Also see [XAML theme resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources).

Comment: The uncompiled styles and templates can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/main/dev)

Comment: Thanks @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, @mm8! I didn't know about those sources. Good to learn new things.

Comment: The WinUI project on GitHub has changed, & WinUI 3 is not yet open source. You can get [the old WinUI 2 uncompiled styles & templates](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/winui2/main/dev) instead.

Comment: Update: I believe the WinUI 3 source code has been available for quite some time, and I was incorrect. For example, here's [`ButtonBackground` from WinUI 3 1.4](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/d4c4e539c55b562e78e7f026195d5b6c8af234ea/dxaml/xcp/dxaml/themes/generic.xaml#L352)