# How to hide or change background of previous and next buttons for Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Calendarview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winui-3

im having a hard time to find a way to hide previous and next buttons for a CalendarView control, the reason why i want to do this is to avoid user confusion since those are disabled anyways. The CalendarView min and max dates are set to only 1 specific month, ie: (1 January 2023 to 31 January 2023).

The previous and next arrows are automatically disabled as intended, however i want to go a step further and make said arrows invisible.

Below you can find XAML Code for reference.

```xml
<VariableSizedWrapGrid
    Margin="0,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <RepositionThemeTransition />
            <EntranceThemeTransition
                FromHorizontalOffset="-200"
                FromVerticalOffset="0"
                IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
        </TransitionCollection>
    </VariableSizedWrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <CalendarView
        x:Name="januaryCalendar"
        x:FieldModifier="Public"
        CornerRadius="20" />
</VariableSizedWrapGrid>
```

And C# code behind to set min and max dates for said control:

```cs
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    januaryCalendar.MinDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,1,1);
    januaryCalendar.MaxDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 31);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `Button`s are named, **PreviousButton** and **NextButton**.

You can bring the DefaultCalendarViewStyle from [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960) and change the `Opacity` to "0" when they are disabled.

First, create a converter because `Enabled` is `bool` and `Opacity` is `double`.

**DisabledToZeroOpacityConverter.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using System;

namespace CalendarViewTests;

public class DisabledToZeroOpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool enabled && enabled is true)
            ? 1.0
            : 0.0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Bring the `DefautCalendarViewStyle` and change the `Opacity` like this.

**NOTE**: The resources below are abbreviated due to the max characters in an answer.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="CalendarViewTests.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:CalendarViewTests"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:DisabledToZeroOpacityConverter x:Key="DisabledToZeroOpacityConverter" />
        <Style
            x:Key="CustomCalendarViewStyle"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultCalendarViewStyle}"
            TargetType="CalendarView">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarView">
                        <Border
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                            <Border.Resources>
                                ...
                            </Border.Resources>
                            <Grid
                                MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.MinViewWidth}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Button
                                        x:Name="HeaderButton"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                        Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.HeaderText}"
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.HasMoreViews}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource HeaderNavigationButtonStyle}" />
                                    <!-- PreviousButton -->
                                    <Button
                                        x:Name="PreviousButton"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource CalendarViewNavigationPreviousButtonMargin}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        Content="&#xEDDB;"
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.HasMoreContentBefore}"
                                        Opacity="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource DisabledToZeroOpacityConverter}}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}" />
                                    <!-- NextButton -->
                                    <Button
                                        x:Name="NextButton"
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Margin="{ThemeResource CalendarViewNavigationNextButtonMargin}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        Content="&#xEDDC;"
                                        IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.HasMoreContentAfter}"
                                        Opacity="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource DisabledToZeroOpacityConverter}}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource NavigationButtonStyle}" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Border
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Height="1"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="1" />
                                <Grid
                                    x:Name="Views"
                                    Grid.Row="2">
                                    ...
                                </Grid>

                            </Grid>

                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            ...
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Border>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <VariableSizedWrapGrid
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <RepositionThemeTransition />
                <EntranceThemeTransition
                    FromHorizontalOffset="-200"
                    FromVerticalOffset="0"
                    IsStaggeringEnabled="False" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </VariableSizedWrapGrid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <CalendarView
            x:Name="januaryCalendar"
            x:FieldModifier="Public"
            CornerRadius="20"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomCalendarViewStyle}" />
    </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Hello, i tried your code but it crashes as soon as i open the calendar page: Crashes at: App.g.i.cs #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION UnhandledException += (sender, e) => { if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); }; #endif with error Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD2F056328 (Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll) in AppName.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x000002845DF6C500, 0x0000000000000004)

Comment: Sorry. I needed to abbreviate the resources because it was too large for an answer. I should've mention that explicitly. As I mentioned in my answer, you can get the entire style in [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).

Comment: Thank you very much, after copying all the 482 lines and changing only the previous and next buttons codes as in your answer, it worked! Is there really no way to avoid copying so much unnecessary data just to change 2 lines of xaml code?