# WinUI 3/WASDK 1.3 How do I shorten the width of the month on a DatePicker control?

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFiB2.png)

I am trying to see what I could use here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/DatePicker_themeresources.xaml
But it just confuses me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try to modify the value of `Width` on [line 327](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/DatePicker_themeresources.xaml#L327).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it this way.

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<DatePicker x:Name="DatePickerControl" />
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DatePickerControl.LayoutUpdated += DatePickerControl_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    private void DatePickerControl_LayoutUpdated(object? sender, object e)
    {
        double monthControlWidth = 70;

        if (this.DatePickerControl.FindDescendant<Grid>(x => x.Name is "FlyoutButtonContentGrid") is Grid flyoutButtonContentGrid &&
            flyoutButtonContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count > 0)
        {
            flyoutButtonContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(monthControlWidth, GridUnitType.Star);
        }

        if (VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopupsForXamlRoot(this.DatePickerControl.XamlRoot)
            .FirstOrDefault() is Popup popup &&
            popup.Child is DatePickerFlyoutPresenter datePickerFlyoutPresenter &&
            datePickerFlyoutPresenter.FindDescendant<Grid>(x => x.Name is "PickerHostGrid") is Grid pickerHostGrid &&
            pickerHostGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count > 0)
        {
            pickerHostGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].Width = new GridLength(monthControlWidth, GridUnitType.Star);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the names of each element in the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75318161/where-is-the-generic-xaml-file-located).

Comment: This approach worked like magic! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Can you accept the answer so we can close this session?