# NavigationView WinUI3 at right

Tags: winui-3

I have a [navigation view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview) at the left side of my app, works ok. I would like to add another control like that to the right.

I did not find any way to position the control like that so, is it a feasible solution to put another control and apply a transform matrix in order to mirror it at the right?

Currently I have a stackpanel with a collection of vertical button but I like the navigation view more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to re-style `NavigationView`.

Bring the default `Style` for `NavigationView` from the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960). Make sure that the version matches your **WindowsAppSDK**'s version.

The minimal changes you need to make:

- Set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right` on the *PaneToggleButtonGrid*.
- Set the `PanePlacement` to `Right` on the *RootSplitView*.
- Set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right` on the *PaneContentGrid*.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Page
    x:Class="RightNavigationViewExample.ShellPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:RightNavigationViewExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style
            x:Key="RightNavigationViewStyle"
            TargetType="controls:NavigationView">
            <Setter Property="PaneToggleButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonStyle}" />
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CompactPaneLength" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewCompactPaneLength}" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{ThemeResource OverlayCornerRadius}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:NavigationView">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                            <!--  Button grid  -->
                            <Grid
                                x:Name="PaneToggleButtonGrid"
                                Width="48"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Canvas.ZIndex="100">

                                <!--  ABBREVIATED  -->

                                <!--  Displaymode (compact/minimal/normal) left  -->
                                <SplitView
                                    x:Name="RootSplitView"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemSeparatorForeground}"
                                    BorderThickness="{ThemeResource NavigationViewBorderThickness}"
                                    CompactPaneLength="{TemplateBinding CompactPaneLength}"
                                    CornerRadius="{Binding Source={ThemeResource OverlayCornerRadius}, Converter={StaticResource RightCornerRadiusFilterConverter}}"
                                    DisplayMode="Inline"
                                    IsPaneOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsPaneOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    OpenPaneLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.OpenPaneWidth}"
                                    PaneBackground="{ThemeResource NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground}"
                                    PanePlacement="Right">
                                    <SplitView.Pane>
                                        <Grid
                                            x:Name="PaneContentGrid"
                                            Margin="{ThemeResource NavigationViewPaneContentGridMargin}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            BorderBrush="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemSeparatorForeground}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.LeftPaneVisibility}">
                                    <!--  ABBREVIATED  -->

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!--  RightNavigationView  -->
    <Grid>
        <NavigationView
            SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged"
            Style="{StaticResource RightNavigationViewStyle}">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem
                    Content="Home"
                    Tag="RightNavigationViewExample.HomePage">
                    <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                        <NavigationViewItem
                            Content="Page A"
                            Tag="RightNavigationViewExample.PageA" />
                    </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, with less code, is by getting the target items and changing the properties directly.

You can get the target items using the `VisualTreeHelper` but it's easier using the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI) NuGet package.

First, name your `NavigationView` control, e.g. *RightNavigationViewControl*.

```xml
<NavigationView
    x:Name="RightNavigationViewControl"
    SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem
            Content="Home"
            Icon="Home"
            Tag="RightNavigationViewExample.HomePage">
            <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem
                    Content="Page A"
                    Tag="RightNavigationViewExample.PageA" />
            </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
</NavigationView>
```

Then get the target items using the `FindDescendant` extension method from the **CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI** and change the properties like this:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;

namespace RightNavigationViewExample;

public sealed partial class ShellPage : Page
{
    public ShellPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.RightNavigationViewControl.Loaded += RightNavigationViewControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void RightNavigationViewControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.RightNavigationViewControl.FindDescendant<Grid>(x => x.Name is "PaneToggleButtonGrid") is Grid paneToggleButtonGrid &&
            this.RightNavigationViewControl.FindDescendant<SplitView>(x => x.Name is "RootSplitView") is SplitView rootSplitView &&
            this.RightNavigationViewControl.FindDescendant<Grid>(x => x.Name is "PaneContentGrid") is Grid paneContentGrid)
        {
            paneToggleButtonGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            rootSplitView.PanePlacement = SplitViewPanePlacement.Right;
            paneContentGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        }
    }
}
```