# WinUI grid and swapchain panel questions

Tags: xaml, winapi, winui-3

My app currently is a mix of WinUI and Win32 elements, that is, a top level window with a [MenuBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.menubar?view=winui-2.8) at the top, and one [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid?view=winrt-22621) with 3 columns: One [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview) at the left, another one at the right using the techniques discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76292326/navigationview-winui3-at-right) and between them I put a normal Win32 HWND aimed to show the main interface of my real time audio/video/image editor drawn with Direct2D.

The idea is now to replace the middle HWND with a [SwapchainPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel?view=winrt-22621) so I have a full WinUI interface.

This time the layout is as such:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition ></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <NavigationView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="LeftN"  .... >
    ...
    </NavigationView>
    <SwapChainPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="scp" ></SwapChainPanel>
    <NavigationView  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="RightN" ...>
    </NavigationView>
```

1. My SwapChain panel isn't resizing when the left/right navs are opened or closed, it stays fixed.

[image]
[image]

2. My swapchain panel's height gets the maximum height of the nav that shows the more controls, it doesn't fully occupy the window. How do I tell it to take the entire height?

[image]

3. The SwapChain drawing is much slower, compared to the Win32 native window. Is this a limitation of the current implementation?

Best & Thanks,

Comment: SwapChainPanel should work fine. You can check it's integration and perf with WinUI3 in this (C#) sample here https://github.com/smourier/DirectN/tree/master/DirectN/DirectN.WinUI3.MinimalD3D11 and between navigation views with a Xaml like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/tph2S2Mu or please provide some reproducible code

Comment: Can you set HorizontalAlignment="Strech" and VerticalAlignment="Strech" on the SwapChainPanel ?