# How to eliminate the WinUI3 TextBox underscore at runtime?

Tags: textbox, runtime, winui-3, winui

I've been scratching my head over what should be a very simple problem.  I've been developing GUIs for decades, but I'm something of a tyro with WinUI 3. I'm developing a Maui custom Entry (WinUI TextBox) control, and have access at runtime to the native  control. It displays a rather annoying underscore character I want to get rid of since I'm implementing my own border; I want to either eliminate it programmatically, or render it invisible by setting its color to Transparent.  I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to do this simple task. Can anyone suggest an appropriate path? I've been Googling and Binging everywhere and even ChatGPT doesn't offer a solution.

I have no idea what to try at this point. I see no way to influence the underscore without also changing the text.

Comment: Do you mean the bottom border (usually skyblue) of the `TextBox` that appears when you edit the text?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. I want to make it transparent without affecting the color of any text entered. I'm wrapping it inside an animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line at the bottom border of `TextBox` is a `Border` named "BorderElement".

In order to access this element inside `TextBox`, you can use the `VisualTreeHelper` but it's easier using the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI) NuGet package.

```cs
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.TextBoxControl
        .FindDescendants()
        .OfType<Border>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name is "BorderElement") is Border borderElement)
    {
        borderElement.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

You can see how this "BorderElement" is in the "DefaultTextBoxStyle" in the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).

Comment: Thanks! In Maui I don't have access to generic.xaml, but C# code I can use to alter the control at runtime. If your suggestion works, I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew above offered a potential solution that unfortunately did not pan out since the code I was attempting to interact with returned null to FindDescendants. However, Andrew ***did*** get me aimed at the proper part of the WinUI 3 docs that resulting in my finding a solution.

Given a WinUI TextBox control, the best way to eliminate the border is:

```
textBox.BorderThickness = default;
```

Since the default border thickness is zero, this offers the solution I needed. Thank you, Andrew, for pointing me in the right direction.