# How can I add a header to a DropDownButton in WinUI 3?

Tags: xaml, label, winui-3, dropdownbutton

In WinUI 3, `TextBox` and `NumberBox` controls support a `Header` property that adds text above the control to label the input field. I would like the same sort of thing for a `DropDownButton` control, but the `Header` property is not supported for that control.

I tried working around this limitation by wrapping the `DropDownButton` with a `StackPanel` to group it with a `TextBlock`, but the text doesn't line up correctly with the text of the headers of other controls in the same row.

Is there a way to do this without abandoning the use of the `Header` property altogether? I know that I could just not use the `Header` property for any of the controls and instead have 2 rows for each row of input controls, one for text labels and another for the input controls. It seems like a kludge to do it that way.

Below is an example for illustration. In the following user control, the `TextBlock` text for the `B0 (T)` and `Pulse Sequence` labels don't align with the headers for the other controls in the same row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserControl
    x:Class="The.Fully.Qualified.Class.Name"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="MrAcquisitionParametersGrid" 
          Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          Style="{ThemeResource BorderedGridStyle}">
        <Grid.Resources>

        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                       Margin="10 10 10 0" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                MR Acquisition Parameters
        </TextBlock>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LabelTextStyle}">
                B0 (T)
            </TextBlock>
            <DropDownButton Content="1.5" x:Name="FieldStrength">
                <DropDownButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="1.5"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="3.0"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="4.7"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="7.0"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="9.4"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </DropDownButton.Flyout>
            </DropDownButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <NumberBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                   Width="90"
                   Header="Flip Angle (°)"
                   x:Name="FlipAngle"/>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource LabelTextStyle}">
                Pulse Sequence
            </TextBlock>
            <DropDownButton Content="FLASH" x:Name="PulseSequence">
                <DropDownButton.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="FLASH"/>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="RARE"/>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </DropDownButton.Flyout>
            </DropDownButton>
        </StackPanel>
        <NumberBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                   Header="Acquisition Interval (s)"
                   x:Name="AcquisitionInterval"/>
        <NumberBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" 
                   Header="Echo Time (ms)"
                   x:Name="EchoTime"/>
        <NumberBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" 
                   Header="Repetition Time (ms)"
                   x:Name="RepetitionTime"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see the style of `NumberBox`es in [Generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).

```xml
<Style TargetType="controls:NumberBox">
    ...
</Style>
```

You can find that `TextBoxTopHeaderMargin` is applied to the header control. `TextBoxTopHeaderMargin` is also defined in the *Generic.xaml*.

```xml
<Thickness x:Key="TextBoxTopHeaderMargin">0,0,0,8</Thickness>
```

So something like this should do:

```xml
<Grid
    Margin="10"
    ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto"
    RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
    <NumberBox
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Header="Header" />

    <Grid
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto">
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="0"
            Margin="{StaticResource TextBoxTopHeaderMargin}"
            Text="Select an item" />
        <DropDownButton
            Grid.Row="1"
            Content="Items">
            <DropDownButton.Flyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 3" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </DropDownButton.Flyout>
        </DropDownButton>
    </Grid>

    <NumberBox
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Header="Header" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. When I tried it, the baseline of the text above the DropDownButton didn't line up with the baseline of the header text above other controls that are in the same row.

Comment: Weird. The code is from a sample app I created for this answer. I update my answer with the code I used to check the alignments.

Comment: I played around with it some more yesterday and found that it does work if I remove all non-default margins from all of the other controls. I suppose with enough tinkering I could make something workable. Ultimately, what I've decided is that WinUI is just too bleeding edge a technology at this point in time and lacking the supporting tools (like a WYSIWYG tool for UI design) necessary to make it productive for me to use routinely.

Comment: Yes. If you want to align your controls, you need to remove custom margins or at least apply margins that result aligning them.