# Add button in TokenizingTextBox

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, winui

I would like to  add a button in TokenizingTextBox thus when user clicks on it a DialogBox appears, or if it's not possible I would like to change behaviour of the standard Add button '+' so once user click on it DialogBox appears.

Does anybody know how to do it ?

Here is my XAML code

```xml
                <!--Add tokenized text box-->
<controls:TokenizingTextBox
    x:Name="TokenBox"   
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind  ViewModel.SelectedTokens  }"
    PlaceholderText="Add Locations"                  
    MaxHeight="104"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    TextMemberPath="Text"
    TokenDelimiter=","
    MaximumTokens="3" 
    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
    Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.StateMachineScanPath}">
    <controls:TokenizingTextBox.SuggestedItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Accept"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="4,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:TokenizingTextBox.SuggestedItemTemplate>
    <controls:TokenizingTextBox.QueryIcon >
        <SymbolIconSource Symbol="Add"/>                        
    </controls:TokenizingTextBox.QueryIcon>
</controls:TokenizingTextBox>
```

Appreciate your help in advance,
Best regards,
Maks.

Comment: I'm not sure if this `TokenizingTextBox` has a standard Add button. Can you show your code around it?

Comment: Hi Andrew! Sure, pls see code in updated subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960) the button's name is "QueryButton". Using the `FindDescendants() extension method from the **CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI** NuGet package, you can do something like this:

```cs
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.TokenizingTextBoxControl
        .FindDescendants()
        .OfType<Button>()
        .Where(x => x.Name is "QueryButton")
        .FirstOrDefault() is not Button queryButton)
    {
        return;
    }

    queryButton.Click += QueryButton_Click;
}

private void QueryButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Show your ContentDialog.
}
```

Comment: My friend, you saved me once again! Thank you so much sir!