# DispatcherQueue bottleneck in WinUI3

Tags: c#, dispatcher, winui-3

I have a desktop application which has several charts and I should periodically update them using `DispatcherQueue`. I have a window which shows pictures to the customer. I need to use `DispatcherQueue` to update pictures in this new window also.

I got a problem there. `DispatcherQueue` turned into a bottleneck in my application. It seems there is only one instance of `DispatcherQueue` for each `thread` and as long as the `WinUI` application's `UI` is running under a single thread, I have this issue in all other windows created by the application. which causes a lots of ugly delays in the new window.

Is there any way to create a window in a new thread to get a new `DispatcherQueue` instance and get rid of this unwelcome `lags` ?

Sample code:

I have 4 chart (from DevExpress libraries) which are getting updated each 50 milliseconds.

like below:

```
// RecordingPageViewModel.cs    

Chart1.Data = mainDataSource.Skip(_lastFrame).Take(7500);
DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(new DispatcherQueueHandler(() =>
{
    Chart1.UpdateData();
});

Chart2.Data = mainDataSource.Skip(_lastFrame).Take(7500);
DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(new DispatcherQueueHandler(() =>
{
    Chart3.UpdateData();
});

// same goes for Chart3 and Chart4
```

here is the other window, in this window I check something every 100 milli-seconds and on specific conditions I show something to the client let say I show him 1 image every 700 milliseconds:

```
// CustomerPicturesViewModel.cs

public void ShowNextImage()
{
    // Capture time here.
    DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(new DispatcherQueueHandler(() =>
    {
        // Capture time here again (Shows on average 40-60 milli second delay).
        var image = findNextImage();
        CurrentImage = image;
    });
}
```

additional info: my main application follows `WinUI3` template studio structure and I have `WindowEx` windows.

I just want to run the new window in another thread to decrease the overhead of existing `DispatcherQueue` on the main application thread.

Comment: The dispatcher queue exists to allow the developer to ensure some piece of code (a task) will run on the UI thread because it needs to (many UI components can only be used from the UI thread). This is not specific to WinUI3. So yes it's can be a bottleneck (calls to it are serialized) if not properyly used but it seems you're using it for other purposes. *"I have a desktop application which has several charts and I should periodically update them using DispatcherQueue"* why?

Comment: It's project definition. I should record some signals and operator should see those signals online. at the same time I need to show some pictures to the customer.

Comment: That doesn't say much more. It all depends on details, number and rate of changes, how it's code, etc. Difficult to help w/o some real reproducing code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier I have added extra source codes that helps u to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes accessing the UI is a bottleneck, no you can't create more `DispatcherQueue` instances. You're going to have to be clever and efficient with your UI updates if you want to get rid of the lag e.g. batching updates, reducing the frequency of some less important updates etc.

Comment: @HasaniH, It's acceptable that we are limited in main application window. but I want to do this in another window. I don't understand why `DispatcherQueue` is limited to the current thread. I can't even create new window in a separated window.

Comment: You can quite easily create a DispatcherQueue on another thread, but it's pretty useless w/o a Xaml window. You can also create a Xaml window, but it's a bit more complicated, here is an example you can try https://gist.github.com/smourier/d1961e2a8d18e762746cebe5948d36db I'm not sure it will solve your main performance issues though

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the source code. but I cant found `WindowsXamlManager` I have installed some nuget  packages but still it doesn't recognize it. my target os is set to `10.0.22621.756`

Comment: WindowsXamlManager is in Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Hosting. Make sure you update the WinApp SDK and WinUI3  nuget packages to the latest version (1.4)

Comment: @SimonMourier it throws into an exception `The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'`

Comment: I guess you didn't use the code properly I've put a complete project here https://github.com/smourier/WinUI3Windows

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the code . It's working. I think there might be some issue with `WindowEx`. I'm using `WinUI3`'s template studio. because `WindowEx` brings a lots of useful features. I will try to make use of ur code. Tnx alot bro 

Comment: WindowEx is not so useful with recent versions of WinUI3 that has AppWindow (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow).

Comment: 50ms rate might be too fast for UI. I would also recommend updating your data on a background thread and update the UI using the `PeriodicTimer` but on a slower rate. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837058/2411960) you can see how to use the `PeriodicTimer`.

Comment: I would also recommend that you update your charts with some delay between the charts.  Use Periodic Timer to put a 100-200 ms interval between sending updates for individual charts.

Comment: tnx guys , @AndrewKeepCoding your solution looks too fine as it doesnt need to directly deal with Dispatcher I will try it.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have tried to use ur code in my solution it doesn't works still. I migrated my `WindowEx` to `Window` before doing that, next I tried to create an empty WinUI3 project using `TemplateStudio` it throws same exception still (With `Window`). here is my source code on that empty project: https://github.com/Reza-Noei/WinU3-MultiThreadWindow. Tnx for any help 

Comment: Because you're running the code on another thread than the UI thread, so it's already too late. Go to this line https://github.com/Reza-Noei/WinU3-MultiThreadWindow/blob/main/TemplateStudioSample/App.xaml.cs#L104 and replace *"await App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args)"* by *"_ = App.GetService<IActivationService>().ActivateAsync(args);"*

Comment: @SimonMourier sry for late answer. I was working on several features past days. It worked like a hell bro. My new `window` has it's own `DispatcherQueue` and its so good. As I may understood from ur code, your running the UI in a separated `Task`. I don't know how it convinced to allow me to have another thread for UI.