# How to change or override the default colour in winUi3?

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3

I Developed an application for a local purpose and it's more important to them to have their colours on the application instead of whichever the computer's configured to use. I want to change customized colour in this application to that would be very helpful.
System's themes applied in my app like Radio buttons and DataGrid selected rows.

```xml
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="#1466a5" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="Green" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="Blue" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>`
```

It is not working in winui3

Comment: Where are  you declaring these resources?

Comment: This resource declared in App.xaml.

Answer (score 1):

For the `CheckBox` control, these are the resources you might want to check:

- CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillChecked
- CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPointerOver
- CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPressed
- CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedDisabled

You can find them in the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).

This is a working example:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="ThemeDictionariesExample.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ThemeDictionariesExample">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!--  Other merged dictionaries here  -->
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillChecked"
                                Color="Pink" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPointerOver"
                                Color="LightPink" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPressed"
                                Color="LightPink" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedDisabled"
                                Color="LightPink" />
                        </ResourceDictionary>
                        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillChecked"
                                Color="Green" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPointerOver"
                                Color="LightGreen" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPressed"
                                Color="LightGreen" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedDisabled"
                                Color="LightGreen" />
                        </ResourceDictionary>
                        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillChecked"
                                Color="Blue" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPointerOver"
                                Color="LightBlue" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedPressed"
                                Color="LightBlue" />
                            <SolidColorBrush
                                x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillCheckedDisabled"
                                Color="LightBlue" />
                        </ResourceDictionary>
                    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--  Other app resources here  -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="ThemeDictionariesExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:ThemeDictionariesExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                Click="DefaultButton_Click"
                Content="Default" />
            <Button
                Click="LightButton_Click"
                Content="Light" />
            <Button
                Click="DarkButton_Click"
                Content="Dark" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <ToggleButton Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ThemeDictionariesExample;
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();

    private void DefaultButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Default;
    }

    private void LightButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
    }

    private void DarkButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied your code in my sample program without any changes, button change to RadioButton for my purpose. But still system theme colour applied for radio buttons.

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it helps.