# how to selected tree view item foreground change in winui3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am in beginner in Winui 3.
Actually, I am trying to Tree View selected item foreground change in winui3.
I didn't get the Tree View selected item foreground color change key. I want like key.
Give me a solution.  Thanks in advance.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.TreeViewItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTreeViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="#2CACE3" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="#2CACE3" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TreeViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed" Color="#2CACE3" />
    </TreeView.Resources>

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModel:TreeNodeModel">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{x:Bind DisplayText}" />
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: You can find other resources in [microsoft-ui-xaml/dev/TreeView
/TreeView_themeresources.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/df0800178657c470eb9f25ef185ce906e8da3279/dev/TreeView/TreeView_themeresources.xaml#L65) as @AndrewKeepCoding answered.

Comment: this is also didn't working fine

Comment: [Why do you say that didn't working?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h4hL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Something like should do the trick:

```xml
<TreeView x:Name="TreeViewControl">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="TreeViewItemForegroundSelected"
            Color="SkyBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver"
            Color="SkyBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed"
            Color="SkyBlue" />
        <SolidColorBrush
            x:Key="TreeViewItemForegroundSelectedDisabled"
            Color="SkyBlue" />
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.RootNodes>
        <TreeViewNode Content="Item A">
            <TreeViewNode.Children>
                <TreeViewNode Content="A-1" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="A-2" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="A-3" />
            </TreeViewNode.Children>
        </TreeViewNode>
        <TreeViewNode Content="Item B">
            <TreeViewNode.Children>
                <TreeViewNode Content="B-1" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="B-2" />
                <TreeViewNode Content="B-3" />
            </TreeViewNode.Children>
        </TreeViewNode>
    </TreeView.RootNodes>
</TreeView>
```

You can find the other resources in the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).

Comment: Weird. I actually created a test app for this and works.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I updated my answer.

Comment: If this answer solves your issue, please accept it as the answer so we can close this session.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code then:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3TreeViewExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3TreeViewExample"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TreeView Name="MyTreeView">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/> <!-- Default foreground color -->
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                                <TreeViewItemPresenter
                                    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                    ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    CheckBoxBrush="{TemplateBinding CheckBoxBrush}"
                                    ContentPadding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    CollapseButtonHorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    CheckBoxVisibility="{TemplateBinding CheckBoxVisibility}"
                                    ExpandCollapseButtonVisibility="{TemplateBinding ExpandCollapseButtonVisibility}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplateSelector}"
                                    GlyphBrush="{TemplateBinding GlyphBrush}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="True"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> <!-- Change 'Red' to your desired foreground color -->
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeViewNode Content="Item 1"/>
            <TreeViewNode Content="Item 2"/>
            <TreeViewNode Content="Item 3"/>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this XAML code, we set the ItemContainerStyle for the TreeView to define a custom style for the TreeViewItem. Inside the ControlTemplate of the TreeViewItem, you'll find the TreeViewItemPresenter, where you can customize the appearance of the selected item.

The Style.Triggers section changes the foreground color of the selected item to "Red" when it is selected.

Make sure to replace "Red" with your desired foreground color.

Comment: your solution is apply only wpf, i want winui3