# Is there a way to customize the date picker flyout in win ui 3?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp-xaml, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I want to change the colour of the selection element (the blue bar indicating the current date selection) to #020066 and change the fontfamily of the flyout.

[image]

I've tried using the theme resources for date picker flyout presenter provided in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/DatePicker_themeresources.xaml) but it isn't doing anything.

I haven't really used anything UWP related before so I don't know if I'm missing something. Or is that UI Element uneditable?

Edit:

I found a way to change the font of the datepicker and the color using the app.xaml file.

You override the contentcontroltheme and the datepickerhighlightfill properties like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightFill" Color="#020066"/>
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">/Assets/Fonts/Righteous Regular.ttf/#Righteous</FontFamily>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This flyout is a `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter` and from the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960), you can learn that this is a `Grid` named *HighlightRect*.

To change the `Background` of the *HighlightRect*:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DatePickerControl.LayoutUpdated += DatePickerControl_LayoutUpdated;
}

private void DatePickerControl_LayoutUpdated(object? sender, object e)
{
    if (VisualTreeHelper
        .GetOpenPopupsForXamlRoot(this.XamlRoot)
        .FirstOrDefault() is Popup popup &&
        popup.Child.FindDescendant<Grid>(x => x.Name is "HighlightRect") is Grid highlightRect &&
        popup.Child.FindDescendants().OfType<LoopingSelector>() is IEnumerable<LoopingSelector> loopingSelectors)
    {
        highlightRect.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGreen);

        foreach (LoopingSelector loopingSelector in loopingSelectors)
        {
            loopingSelector.FontSize = 20;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:

`FindDescendant` comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Windows) NuGet package.

Comment: isn't there a way to do this in app.xaml.cs using the theme resources so the other .xaml files have access to that style?

Comment: This worked but but i need a way to make the change available to all future date pickers. Also How do i Change the font.

Comment: I'm not sure why but overriding resources doesn't work for items in `Flyout`s or `Popup`s. You might want to create a custom controls that derives from `DatePicker`. Anyway, I just updated my answer with a solution for the `FontSize`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to set the font family by doing "loopingSelector.FontFamily = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily("/Assets/Fonts/SplineSans-Regular.ttf#Spline Sans")" but it failed and entered debugger mode. Do You know how i can do that?

Comment: Changing FontSize Worked btw. Just FontFamily is having some issues.

Comment: I tried to change the `FontFamil`, but as you already tried, it doesn't let you change it.