# How to customize the scrollbar in WinUi 3

Tags: c#, .net, scrollbar, customization, winui-3

I'm developing a desktop application on WinUI 3 and I have a need to completely change the appearance of the standard scrollbar. I haven't decided yet which scrolling class to use. As far as I understand, I have two options: ScrollView and ScrollViewer, but I don’t understand what their fundamental difference is. In any case, I need to completely change the appearance of the default scrollbar that comes with these classes. Ideally, I would like to use the capabilities of Visual Layer for these purposes, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I would like to know what customization possibilities exist in general, and how I can complete this task

Comment: Change [scrollbar theme resources](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/4c50e610e537aca92afc950c4be1ffb60c2f99d5/dev/CommonStyles/ScrollBar_themeresources.xaml) in the scope of *ScrollView* or *ScrollViewer*?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT, could you please write in more detail how this can be done? I'm completely new to this and don't quite understand how this process happens.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096944/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-date-picker-flyout-in-win-ui-3 for two ways. Particularly @AndrewKeepCoding 's [VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4) solution.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?