# XAML WINUI 3 Text Box uneditable for some odd reason

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, winui

Oddly this should be easier, but i am new to WINUI so maybe i'm being stupid. I would like to put a username and password control in my XAML window that has an icon on the left hand side, embedded within the input control itself. Not on the side. I have this, which works visually for what i'm looking for, but the control doesn't allow me to enter anything in it. Like the below...
[Example of what i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVPj1.png)

```
<TextBox Width="250" Height="32" IsEnabled="True">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Grid>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="5"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Text="&#xF180;" FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

I've tried every variation i can think of, all with varying degrees of success.

Comment: Have you considered using an User Control instead of overriding the template?

Comment: I guess **PART_ContentHost** is from WPF, not WinUI 3. You might need to bring the entire style (or at least essential parts) from *DefaultTextBoxStyle*. You can find it in [Generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960). Or, as @Nick says, create a user control might be a better option.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? or do you need any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the following in your control template:

`<ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />`

Check out the following examples and docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

https://github.com/dotnet/docs-desktop/blob/main/dotnet-desktop-guide/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates.md

Comment: Nope it's there.