# How to disable commandbar buttons scaling

Tags: winui-3

I have Cmdbar with buttons without labels. When changing the scale in the system settings, the size of the appbar button also changes, but the icon size does not change.

[before slaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOukf.png)

[after scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6wv2.png)

Here is my commandbar

```xml
    <Grid>
        <CommandBar Style="{StaticResource OpenDownCommandBar}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsOpen="False" DefaultLabelPosition="Collapsed" Margin="0,15,0,0" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False">
            <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource ImageAppBarButtonStyle}" LabelPosition="Default" >
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Source>
                            <SvgImageSource UriSource="/Assets/icons/svg/open.svg"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource ImageAppBarButtonStyle}" LabelPosition="Default">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <SvgImageSource UriSource="/Assets/icons/svg/save.svg"/>
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </Viewbox>
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Style="{StaticResource ImageAppBarButtonStyle}" LabelPosition="Default">
                <AppBarButton.Content>
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Source>
                            <SvgImageSource UriSource="/Assets/icons/svg/chrpass.svg"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </AppBarButton.Content>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
    </Grid>
```

How to disable system scaling or make Image flexible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least, it seems that the `Viewbox` inside `AppBarButton`s have a fixed size of 16 (hard coded). Something like this should give you some direction:

```cs
private void CommandBar_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not CommandBar commandBar)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (Viewbox viewbox in commandBar.FindDescendants()
            .OfType<Viewbox>()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "ContentViewbox"))
    {
        viewbox.Margin = new Thickness(8);
        viewbox.Height = double.NaN;
        viewbox.Width = double.NaN;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

- You can find the default style in [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).
- `FindDescendants` comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) NuGet package.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?