# Force UWP DatePicker to stretch to full container width

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

I have a DatePicker with HorizontalAlignment set to Stretch, but it only stretches to a certain maximimum width (unlike the blue bar for instance).

I would like to either have the DatePicker's three segments or the middle one stretch proportionally to an arbitrary length.

[image]

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `DatePicker` has a `Button` named "FlyoutButton" which limits the `MaxWidth` of the control itself. You can find it in the [Generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).

So, widening the `MaxWidth` should work:

```xml
<DatePicker
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Loaded="DatePickerControl_Loaded">
```

```cs
private void DatePickerControl_Loaded(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as DatePicker)?
        .FindDescendant<Button>(x => x.Name is "FlyoutButton") is not Button flyoutButton)
    {
        return;
    }

    flyoutButton.MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
}
```

BTW, the `FindDescendant` extension method comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Windows) NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks, that works for Windows.Unfortunately it does not when porting to Android or iOS. Is there perhaps a solution that achieves the same by manipulating the control template directly?