# WinUI 3 Button custom themes

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3

I want my Buttons have their own custom color themes (background, foreground, border, mousein, mouseout, click color, etc.), so if I write something like this:

```
<Button type="Primary">Action1</Button>
<Button type="Secondary">Action2</Button>
```

I will have 2 buttons with different colors. Also those button themes should change the color depending on the main app theme (light/dark).

I'm new in WinUI, could you please help me to achieve this goal?
I dug deep into the colors, themes, brushes, resources, custom controls and eventually got lost.
Do I need to create a custom button? Or control template? Or working just with resources is enough? A lot of custom/user/template controls and resource types are really confusing.

Comment: Define different Button Styles and explicitly Specify the style of buttons by [FrameworkElement.Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.style?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4#microsoft-ui-xaml-frameworkelement-style). See [Apply an implicit or explicit style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-styles#apply-an-implicit-or-explicit-style) for more information.

Comment: Isn't the function of `Type` Property the same as `FrameworkElement.Style` Property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThemeDictionaries` for this:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <Style
                    x:Key="Type1ButtonStyle"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Style>
                <Style
                    x:Key="Type2ButtonStyle"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Style>
                <Style
                    x:Key="Type3ButtonStyle"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <Style
                    x:Key="Type1ButtonStyle"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
                </Style>
                <Style
                    x:Key="Type2ButtonStyle"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
                </Style>
                <Style
                    x:Key="Type3ButtonStyle"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}"
                    TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button
        Content="Type 1"
        Style="{ThemeResource Type1ButtonStyle}" />
    <Button
        Content="Type 2"
        Style="{ThemeResource Type2ButtonStyle}" />
    <Button
        Content="Type 3"
        Style="{ThemeResource Type3ButtonStyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to override resources like:

- ButtonBackgroundPointerOver
- ButtonBackgroundPressed
- etc

I'm afraid you can't use styles. One way to do this is to override the resources on each `Button` because [we can't apply resources with a `Style`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/7479):

```xml
<Button Content="Type 1" Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <SolidColorBrush
                        x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver"
                        Color="Red" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                    <SolidColorBrush
                        x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver"
                        Color="HotPink" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

BTW, you can find the `Button`'s resources in the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960).

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! But how about colors when button is pressed, focused, when the mouse is over it? I didn't find such Setters for Style.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that part of your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there any way to make nested dictionaries? If yes how to access them?

Comment: I saw your additional question. You can create nested dictionaries and it will compile but I guess they just will be merged, and I don't see how it will help you with your original issue.