# WinUI 3 cast UserControl to a Button type

Tags: c#, xaml

I have simple Button UserControl like:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <UserControl
        x:Class="TestProject.Controls.Button"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:TestProject.Controls"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
        <Button x:Name="MyButton" Click="Btn_Click">Aloha!</Button>
    </UserControl>
```

/Controls/Button.xaml.cs:

```cs
    namespace TestProject.Controls
    {
        public sealed partial class Button : UserControl
        {
            private void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                MyButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }
```

Insert it in the main page:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Page
        x:Class="TestProject.Views.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:TestProject.Views"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mycontrols="using:TestProject.Controls">
        <StackPanel>
            <mycontrols:Button />
        </StackPanel>
    </Page>
```

if in `Btn_Click` I cast `var button = (Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Button)sender` there is exception fires says, that can't cast TestProject.Controls.Button to Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Button. It seems that inside the UserControl even if user press button the sender is not the button anyway, but that UserControl.

Now to change the button's background I need call it by name (MyButton), but my original intention is that the UserControl should be the Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Button. Is there any way to cast it to the Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Button type, so by specifying `this.Background =` I can change background color of the button and also make my UserControl has original Microsoft.Ui.Xaml.Controls.Button's Click event so I can specify it in Xaml like `<mycontrols:Button Click="Test_Click" />` to handle click in the page I where inserted it?

Comment: `MyButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));` should work and set the button's `Background` to **Black**. Can you try another colors?

Comment: Please post screenshot that demonstrates that this is not working, code is fine.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller sorry, I messed up here, my question is about other thing, I fixed it, pls check it out.

Comment: In the future, you should post as a new question, changes like this invalidate the existing answer and comments. This is even further misleading to the community than your original question.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that this works:

```cs
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Since you named your `UserControl` "Button", 
    // you need to add the Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace.
    if (sender is not Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button button)
    {
        return;
    }

    button.Resources["ButtonBackgroundPointerOver"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    button.Resources["ButtonBackgroundPressed"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

    // "ButtonBackground" doesn't work 
    // because it's not set when the VisualState changes.
    //button.Resources["ButtonBackground"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

You can see it in the [generic.xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318162/2411960) by searching for "DefaultButtonStyle".

Comment: sorry, my case is a bit more complicated then I described and it seems I messed up with the logic a bit. I'm actually trying to change background of a Button which is inside of UserControl. I updated my question, please check it.

Comment: Since you named your `UserControl` **Button**, things get a bit confusing. Can you try adding the namespace?

Comment: Sure, I edited it for you.

Comment: Did you get to solve you issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is wrong. The reason the cast failed is because you named your custom user control `Button`, so any local references to `Button` type in your code will assume that you mean the local class.

In this case you will either need to create a [*`using` alias*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias) or use the fully qualified namespace to reference the correct `Button` class when you try to cast the control.

```
(sender as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button).Background = 
    new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 60, 90));
```

- It is not a good idea to create your own custom controls with names that are identical to the standard framework controls. The namespace issue will cause issues for many developers.
- A standard practise is to prefix your controls with your *brand* or an acronym for your library. Something like `MatButton` for *My Awesome Tools* button...

If you wanted to bind your button to the user control background then the simplest syntax is to use x:Bind directive as this does not bind to the `DataContext` instead it binds to `this`.

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton"
        Click="Btn_Click"
        Background="{x:Bind Background, Mode=OneWay}">Aloha!</Button>

this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 133, 66, 120));
```

Comment: You are right about the namespace. Thanks.

Comment: That is true, but also irrelevant, use the full namespace for the control that you need when there is a local name clash.

Comment: Thank you! How about such cast in DependencyProperty? If I try perform it in DP I have exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: You really need to ask that in a new question, it is not clear which of these solutions I've proposed you are referring to and it means your code example needs to change again. One question per post ;)

Comment: Why is a cast needed to be apply on [`DependencyProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyproperty.register?view=winrt-22621)? @holycreeper You may need to ask that in a new question with more detail.

Comment: @holycreeper If you are asking this about DependencyProperty then you are missing a lot of information on standard practises. The x:Bind solution is probably a better fit because there is no casting. With DP your code setup is different enough that we need a new question so we can provide an answer that you will be able to consume. With DPs you want to use more of an MVVM approach instead of using a direct link back to the component, you can also use story board triggers instead and do this purely in XAML if you want.